# How to allow List as query params instead of requestbody in pydantic model for fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

So I have a simple fastapi model as follows:

```
 from typing import List
 
 from fastapi import Query, Depends, FastAPI
 from pydantic import BaseModel
 
 class QueryParams(BaseModel):
     req1: float = Query(...)
     opt1: int = Query(None)
     req_list: List[str] = Query(...)
 
 
 app = FastAPI()
 @app.post("/test", response_model=QueryParams)
 def foo(q: QueryParams = Depends()):
     return q
```

which works with the following command: `curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:8000/test?req1=1" -d '{["foo"]}'`

However! I need it to work additionally with allowing the params in the uri request as such:
`curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:8000/test?req1=1&req_list=foo"`

I know that if I took out the `req_list` from the BaseModel, and shoved it in the function header as such

```
 from typing import List
 
 from fastapi import Query, Depends, FastAPI
 from pydantic import BaseModel
 
 class QueryParams(BaseModel):
     req1: float = Query(...)
     opt1: int = Query(None)
 
 
 app = FastAPI()
 @app.post("/test", response_model=QueryParams)
 def foo(q: QueryParams = Depends(), req_list: List[str] = Query(...)):
     return q
```

that it would work, but is there any way to keep it in the basemodel?

Answer (score 3):

Well I figured it out:

```
 from typing import List
 
 from fastapi import Query, Depends, FastAPI
 from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
 
 @dataclass
 class QueryParams:
     req1: float = Query(...)
     opt1: int = Query(None)
     req_list: List[str] = Query(...)
 
 
 app = FastAPI()
 @app.post("/test", response_model=QueryParams)
 def foo(q: QueryParams = Depends()):
     return q
```